# Docker running `linux/amd64` image in apple M1 and getting qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped

Tags: linux, docker, apple-m1

I am running a `linux/amd64` image on docker with Apple M1 system. Getting this `qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped` error while running tests in the docker. I was using to `platform: linux/amd64` to specify the platform. I found a github issue related to this https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5123.

- Is docker is using `qemu` to run `linux/amd64` image on Apple M1?
- Is there any other way to run the `linux/amd64` image on Apple M1 or should wait for the `arm64` support for the image I am using?

Answer (score 0):

> Is docker is using qemu to run linux/amd64 image on Apple M1?

Yes, docker internally uses qemu to emulate amd64.

> Is there any other way to run the linux/amd64 image on Apple M1 or should wait for the arm64 support for the image I am using?

Currently I don't know about any other way, so you should wait for arm64 support or for fixing qemu or fixing your used image.